# Angular 6 - primeng <p-calendar> required condition

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using the the PrimeNg calendar component in angular 6, and I wish to implement a [required] directive with a condition. 
once I set the "required" with a condition it is always sets to true, no matter what the condition is.

```
<p-calendar 
  [required]="Item.status === 'In Transit'"
  [(ngModel)]="Item.actualPickup" showTime="true" 
  hourFormat="24" showSeconds="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
  [showIcon]="true" showButtonBar="true" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true">
</p-calendar>
```

any idea how can I do this in a template driven form?

Comment: ```[required]="(Item.status === 'In Transit')? true : false"```
wont work ?

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Comment: Can you make it a property like IsInTransit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *ngIf

helps always in these kind of situations where you do not have a deep knowladge about directive.

Use

```
<p-calendar *ngIf = "myboolean == true" 
  [required]="Item.status === 'In Transit'"
  [(ngModel)]="Item.actualPickup" showTime="true" 
  hourFormat="24" showSeconds="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
  [showIcon]="true" showButtonBar="true" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true">
</p-calendar>

<p-calendar *ngIf = "myboolean == false" 
  [required]="Item.status = true"
  [(ngModel)]="Item.actualPickup" showTime="true" 
  hourFormat="24" showSeconds="true" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
  [showIcon]="true" showButtonBar="true" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true">
</p-calendar>
```

Comment: Duplicating the component? it doesn't seems like the best practice.

Comment: ngIf directive does not take place in DOM where beloning condition is false. So considering performance issues it does not have a negative effect. About clean code ? yea sometimes you may do a code loan.

Answer (score 3):

To dynamically add or remove the `required` attribute:

```
<p-calendar [required]="Item.status === 'In Transit' ? '' : null">
```

When the condition is true, this produces the `required` attribute without value (because of `''`):

```
<p-calendar required>
```

else the `required` attribute is left out completely (because of `null`):

```
<p-calendar>
```